# Display list items one after another after 2 sec in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

This is the list

```
places = ["London", "India", "America", "Australia", "Cambodia", "China", 
          "Dubai", "Egypt",  "France", "Germany", "Japan", "Jordan", 
          "Korea", "Myanmar", "Peru", "Russia", "Singapore", "Spain"]
```

I randomised the list:

```
random_place = random.choice(places)
```

Here I have tried to display random items from the list. I have tried using `for` loop and `time.sleep` function but it didn't work.

```
def text():
    game_font = pygame.freetype.SysFont("monospace", 35)
    text_surface, rect = game_font.render(random_place, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text_surface, (680, 420))
   
# Game loop
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((255, 194, 102))  # RGB
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
   
    card()
    text()
    pygame.display.update()
```

It would be great if anyone could solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a timer event. In pygame exists a timer event. Use [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) to repeatedly create a [`USEREVENT`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) in the event queue. The time has to be set in milliseconds.

Choose a new random card, when the timer event occurs:

```py
random_place = random.choice(places)

timer_interval = 2000 # 2000 milliseconds = 2 seconds
timer_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event, timer_interval)

running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((255, 194, 102))  # RGB
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == timer_event:
            random_place = random.choice(places)

    card()
    text()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Note, in pygame customer events can be defined. Each event needs a unique id. The ids for the user events have to be between `pygame.USEREVENT` (24) and `pygame.NUMEVENTS` (32). In this case `pygame.USEREVENT+1` is the event id for the timer event.

Answer (score 2):

I've added two small blocks of code to your code to make this work. It uses the [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) method to retrieve the current time in seconds every iteration of the game loop:

```
import pygame
import random
import time

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 800))

places = ["London", "India", "America", "Australia", "Cambodia", "China", 
          "Dubai", "Egypt",  "France", "Germany", "Japan", "Jordan", 
          "Korea", "Myanmar", "Peru", "Russia", "Singapore", "Spain"]

def text():
    game_font = pygame.freetype.SysFont("monospace", 35)
    text_surface, rect = game_font.render(random_place, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text_surface, (680, 420))

interval = 2 # Set interval in seconds
last_time = time.time() # Get the current time in seconds
random_place = random.choice(places)

# Game loop
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((255, 194, 102))  # RGB
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
   
#    card()
    # If 2 seconds has past since the last update to last_time
    if time.time() - last_time >= interval: 
        random_place = random.choice(places)
        last_time = time.time()
        
    text()
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Output:

[image]